# How to prove these sets are in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal M, \mu)$, I want to show $\nu(E)=\int_Efd\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, where $f$ is nonnegative and $f\in L^1(\mu)$. The definition of $\sigma$-finite measure I use is that if $\Omega = \cup_1^\infty E_n$ where $E_n \in \mathcal M$ and $\nu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n$, then $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure.
So, I write $$\Omega=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{x\in \Omega:|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}\right\}\cup \{{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=0\}}.$$
But, how to show that$\left\{x\in \Omega:|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}\right\}$ and $\{{ x\in \Omega: f(x)=0\}}$ are in $\mathcal M$?

Answer (score 0):

But $f\in L^{1}(\mu)=L^{1}(\Omega,\mu)$ guarantees that $\nu(\Omega)=\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}fd\mu<\infty$, so $\nu$ is a finite measure, no?

Comment: Right. $\nu$ is finite. In Folland's book, he distinguishes a measure being finite and a measure being $\sigma$-finite. A measure $\nu$ is finite if $\nu(\Omega)<\infty$  But the definition of $\sigma$-finite measure is that $\Omega = \cup_1^\infty E_n$ where $E_n \in \mathcal M$ and $\nu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. So I need to show that $E_n \in \mathcal M$.

Comment: A finite measure space must be $\sigma$-finite by choosing $E_{n}=\emptyset$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Do we lose generality if we assume $E_n = \emptyset$ for $n\geq 2$? The definition seems to require $E_n$ be arbitrary

Comment: $\Omega$ is said to be $\nu$ $\sigma$-finite if there exists a sequence $(E_{n})$ with $\nu(E_{n})<\infty$.

Comment: How does the set $\Omega$ being $\sigma$-finite help us to show $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure? What definition of $\sigma$-finite do you use?

Comment: $\sigma$-finite is related to the measure and the $\mathcal{M}$ that we are talking about, but your question is phrasing that $\nu$... is $\sigma$-finite with $\mathcal{M}$ unchanged, so it is about $\nu$, so as long as you manage to find a sequence of sets $(E_{n})$ in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\nu(E_{n})<\infty$, then it goes through.

Comment: So I can just say the integral of each of these subsets of $\Omega$ is finite, then conclude that $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure?

Comment: Yes, you are right.